# How to connect android application with django?

Tags: android, django, android-studio, machine-learning, django-rest-framework

I’m making an android app where I’m going to collect sensor data from the android phone and send a collection of data for machine learning model prediction. I have prepared a jupyter notebook for model fitting. How do I connect the android application with Django local server?

Comment: Do you want continuous streaming sensor data?

Comment: I want to keep a buffer of 1200 data (6 seconds data) and when the buffer is full I send all those data for computation. Then after prediction, the first 200 data(1 second data) will be discarded and the app will record and add more data to the end of the buffer until it gets full again.

Comment: Here are a couple of possible solutions: 1. You could use REST api using Django rest framework and call into it every six seconds 2. You could open up a socket using Django Channels (https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and transmit data every six seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use APIs to send data from android app to Django server.

Rest APIs using Django: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/

Android lib https://square.github.io/retrofit/ to connect to server.

Tutorials: https://www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial

Flow will be:

1. Call APis from Android App to Django server
2. Process the data in Django server
3. Send response to Android App
4. Use response in Android App